# VBA Code throwing Error : Run-Time error 1004 AutoFill Method of Range Class failed

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula, excel-2010

I have below VBA Code.

Based on the values in Entites sheet, it has to Auto Populate in Contributions Sheet.

Here when E_Count is greater than 1, it is working fine. But when E_Count is 1, it is throwing Error as below at the last line of code here: 
**Run-Time error 1004 AutoFill Method of Range Class failed**

```
'Autofill 
Dim MaxRow As Integer
Dim E_Count As Integer
Dim ii As Integer
Dim jj As Integer

MaxRow = Worksheets("Contribution").UsedRange.Rows.Count
E_Count = Worksheets("Entities").UsedRange.Rows.Count - 4

Worksheets("Contribution").Range("F5:G5").Copy Worksheets("Contribution").Range("F6:G" & MaxRow)

Worksheets("Contribution").Range("H4:XFD1048576").Clear

Worksheets("Contribution").Range("G4:G" & MaxRow).AutoFill Destination:=Worksheets("Contribution").Range(Worksheets("Contribution").Cells(4, 7), Worksheets("Contribution").Cells(MaxRow, 6 + E_Count))
```

**Entities Sheet with 2 Entities:** [image]

**Contribution Sheet before Start button click:** 
[image]
Here VBA code makes database call to fill upto Column E. This is like Template here.

**Contribution Sheet after Start button click:** 
[image]

Here the VBA Code is being called on Start button click. Based on the Entities specified in Entities start, it has to Pivot those Entities as in Contributions sheet and auto populate as 100% as it will be in the first cell upto whatever Used data Range is there.

Any Thoughts?

Appreciate your time.

Thanks, 
Rita

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There could be many factors affecting this 

1. Are you sure you want to use `usedrows.count`? Remember that blanks among are not counted. 

2. If you are autofilling a range of size 1 excel will result in error, if so an `on error resume next` will work, but just keep in mind that your data may be one and it will not autofill -what to autofill from g4:g4 for example?- If this should be an input mistake, it should be handled like it.

3. Cell is not existent (have you debugged E_count when the error shows? What happens if it's "-6"?

Comment: Yes. UsedRows.Count is what i want to use. In this Case, users are trained that way to use that Range. Also we provide the Template which they will not change, so the starting cell is consistent.

Comment: Not sure what the issue is... But "On Error Resume Next" Solved the issue.

Comment: you are not autofilling if size is not greater than 0, hence, the error, note that on error resume next should be used only when you know what the error is and you know that it should skip the autofilling -like I said, autofill of one cell-